# Creating and validating (JWT)-tokens with FireBase Auth Emulator

Tags: .net, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, firebase-tools

I aim to issue tokens via firebase admin to use for authentication for local development with the emulator.

Using the FireBase Admin targeting a local project(demo-project) in the emulator. The following code is used to lookup a user and issue and validate a token. But this results is a mismatch of the token audience (aud).
How could this be resolved ?

> Firebase ID token has incorrect audience (aud) claim. Expected
> demo-project but got
> https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit.
> Make sure the ID token comes from the same Firebase project as the
> credential used to initialize this SDK

```
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:9099");
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "demo-project");
    
    var email = [EMAIL];
    
    GoogleCredential dummyCredential =
               GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken("test-token");
    
    var app = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
    {
        Credential = dummyCredential
    });
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(app);
    var user = await auth.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);
    var token = await auth.CreateCustomTokenAsync(user.Uid);
    var verifiedToken = await auth.VerifyIdTokenAsync(token);
```

It seems that the *audience* depends on how the Admin SDK is initiated, and that is the cause of the mismatch. How should the SDK be initiated for emulator development ?
Hoping that it possible to achieve this without any ties to any firebase hosted project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote two util functions for sign-in, with token or email/password.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIREBASE_AUTH_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:9099");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GCLOUD_PROJECT", "demo-project");

var email = [EMAIL];

GoogleCredential dummyCredential =
            GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken("test-token");

var app = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
{
    Credential = dummyCredential,
    ProjectId = "demo-project"
});

var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
var user = await auth.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);
var token = await auth.CreateCustomTokenAsync(user.Uid);
var verifiedToken = await auth.VerifyIdTokenAsync(await SignIn.FireBaseSignIn(token));
```

Instead of using the creating a custom token, signing in an existing user via a sign-in util;

```
var user = await auth.GetUserByEmailAsync(email);
var verifiedToken = await auth.VerifyIdTokenAsync(await SignIn.FireBaseSignIn(email, [PASSWORD]));
```

Sign-in utils;

```
public record SignInResponse(string IdToken);

public static async Task<string> FireBaseSignIn(string email, string password)
{
    var authClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9099/")
    };

    var res = await authClient.PostAsJsonAsync("identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=fake-api-key",
        new { email, password, returnSecureToken = true });
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var json = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<SignInResponse>();

    return json.IdToken;
}

public static async Task<string> FireBaseSignIn(string token)
{
    var authClient = new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9099/")
    };

    var res = await authClient.PostAsJsonAsync("identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=fake-api-key",
        new { token, returnSecureToken = true });
    res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    var json = await res.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<SignInResponse>();

    return json.IdToken;
}
```